# How is that possible to insert data in asynchronous mode using FMDB in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just developing an application about to save a notes. I have single view. on a view I have a 3 page. just like swiping from 1 to second, second to third, and i'll just load the data from the database.. something like that. I have large number of data of single note. because in a noteview so many functionality that can not I describe here. so I just want insert data in a background mode or asynchronous mode using FMDB.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0) { // 1
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { // 2

                            }
                        }
```

this is not work for me when i move to from one view to second view. it wait to insert data from one view and then go after to second view.

Answer (score 0):

You should use background thread. In your thread it's just run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block. So to solve your problem :-

```
 let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
 let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
 dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
   //This is run on the background queue
 })
```